# How to configure a promotion like Buy X get Y for price Z?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am supposed to design a promotion like when a particular product is added to the cart, the other product should be sold for a specific price.

I was seeing some out of the box templates but I could not find the :Buy X Get Y for Z dollars type of promotion template.Also perfect partner fixed price looked to be the one, but there I had difficulty as the selection criteria is not necessarily useful for this.

Comment: From what I know this can not be achieved using the OOTB conditions and actions. Maybe if you add the OOTB condition: "Qualifying Product" for both products(you need both of your Products in your cart in the end) and the Fixed Cart Discount action you can achieve a similar scenario